# Get execution time for Selenium step

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-rc

I need to run some Selenium tests with NUnit, and I need to get the execution time for each step. Here's a test example:

```
[Test]
public void TheGoogleTest()
{
     selenium.Open("/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=8bUxV7eRNen06ATIq66wBw");
     selenium.Click("link=Imagini");
     selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
     selenium.Type("id=lst-ib", "test");
     selenium.Click("name=btnG");
     selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
}
```

Normally I would measure each call by writing code before and after each call to "selenium.Click()" or "selenium.Type()", but in my case I just receive some files and I have to run them with NUnit and export an xml file with the execution time of each step and test.
One way would be to create a program which reads each .cs file with tests and insert code before each line with a step, so the time be written to the output I specify, but I want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: you can use the method interception, in post-sharp: http://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception

Comment: thanks, but I don't think it can help me that much
I don't write the tests, they are files generated by Selenium, so I have two options


1. Detect events lick click/open... and measure their execution time


2. Modify files and insert code that measures the time before and after the call, and output it in some xml file

Comment: I finally found a solution. The Selenium library is open source, available on Github, so I will put my code for timing each step inside the library and recompile it.